# Get an accurate Y value from a raster on R

Tags: r, coordinates, r-raster

I am trying to get the exact position of a raster in space in order to precisely determine line parameters that overlap elements of my raster. However, the ymin and ymax coordinates are always rounded (always presented as integers) in the repository I use.

[image]

```
> ymin(vegetation_raster_1)
[1] 4894166
```

As we can see graphically, ymin is not exactly 4894166 but near 4894165.7.

```
> vegetation_raster_1
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 94, 95, 8930  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.05744, 0.05744  (x, y)
extent      : 284823.7, 284829.2, 4894166, 4894171  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : band1 
values      : 0, 0.3753507  (min, max)
```

I have tried with extent() function, but this gave the same result.

```
> extent(vegetation_raster_1)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 284823.7 
xmax        : 284829.2 
ymin        : 4894166 
ymax        : 4894171
```

Does anyone know of a way to get ymin and ymax with at least one digit after the decimal point?

Regards,

François

Comment: Can you provide some data that shows the problem that can be copy-and-pasted so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. A solution to the problem has been provided by Robert before I sent an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are not rounded. It is possible that not all decimals are shown when you print them. You can control that in different ways. For example

```
x <- 12.12300000100000123   
x
#[1] 12.123
sprintf("%.10f", x)
#[1] "12.1230000010"
```